# How do I change the name of an album in Photos on my Mac

Tags: macos, photos.app

How do I change the name of an album in Photos my Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Select name of album in the sidebar
- Click on the name again to edit
- Or: click on album name at the top of the pictures to edit